WooCommerce Disallow ClearPay (AfterPay in some regions) messaging for specific user roles on product page
I have a wholesale side of website which when users logon are given the role "wholesale". As these are trade customers I want to disable Clearpay on all product, category, cart and checkout pages. I have been able to disable the checkout page but really struggling with the individual product page and category pages.
This is the code I have tried to get to work.
add_filter( 'clearpay_is_product_supported', 'clearpay_ips_callback', 10, 2 );
function clearpay_ips_callback( $bool_result, $product  ) {

    if( wc_current_user_has_role( 'wholesale' ) ) {
        $bool_result = false;
    }
    return $bool_result;
}

Can anyone help please
